# Can't open registry subkey

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, registry

**Can't open registry subkey** even if I try to open in both - **x64 and x32** registry. I'm trying to get username of logged in visual studio user.

```
@"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ConnectedUser\IdeUser\Cache"
```

Can't see **IdeUser**, but **Cache** returns NULL.

```
const string SubKey = @"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ConnectedUser\IdeUser\Cache";
const string EmailAddressKeyName = "EmailAddress";
const string UserNameKeyName = "DisplayName";

RegistryKey localMachineRegistry64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey reg64 = localMachineRegistry64.OpenSubKey(SubKey, false);

if (reg64 != null)
{
    return reg64.GetValue(SubKey, true).ToString();
}

//Check the 32-bit registry for "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE" if not found in the 64-bit registry:
RegistryKey localMachineRegistry32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
RegistryKey reg32 = localMachineRegistry32.OpenSubKey(SubKey, false);

if (reg32 != null)
{
    return reg32.GetValue(SubKey, true).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like security restrictions on the registry. Have you tried elevating permissions on your host app? Can you also post your code that is 'failing'

Comment: Hello, please look at my comment below/

Comment: Yes, it isn't an answer. But DotNetHitMan asked me to provide an example. I can't put too much code in a comment - only in a post..

Comment: @Vnuuk If you press `edit`(it is located under the tags) in your question you can edit the question and add there the code.

Comment: reg32.GetValue(SubKey, true) can never be correct.  Use the value name, not the key name.

Comment: You are right for this example.. But I don't step into if statement because reg64 and reg32 are always null.. But I can see value in regedit program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested you code and it works as I would expect (to a point). I can access the SubKey. *Note I am running VS as administrator. (right click on the VS exe and run as admin, I am also a local admin my dev machine, so I have un-restricted registry access).

However your code is a little interesting as your not actually accessing the values in the registry by calling `GetValue(SubKey,true)`, in my example I altered accordingly.

```
const string SubKey = @"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ConnectedUser\IdeUser\Cache";
const string EmailAddressKeyName = "EmailAddress";
const string UserNameKeyName = "DisplayName";

RegistryKey localMachineRegistry64 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey reg64 = localMachineRegistry64.OpenSubKey(SubKey, false);

if (reg64 != null)
{
    //******** This is just an example of getting the user name and email.
    //get user name and email from the selected sub key.
    var userName = reg64.GetValue(UserNameKeyName, String.Empty).ToString();
    var emailAddress = reg64.GetValue(EmailAddressKeyName, String.Empty).ToString();
    //return a bool and pass back the userName and email as out parms?
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT -

If registry access continues to be an issue you can monitor registry access via ProcMon from [sysinternals](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson5/all/).

Comment: That is interesting.. I've run visual studio as administrator, but still having null for gegistry key.

Comment: @Vnuuk OK have you tested the registry access with procmon?